Is the classifying stack of an abelian variety separated?
If $G/k$ is an algebraic group, a necessary condition for $BG$ to be separated over $k$ is that $G$ is proper over $k$. Assuming that $G$ is smooth and connected we are reduced to the case of an abelian variety. Is it also sufficient in this case?
I have trouble to understand this because I know that the $\operatorname{Isom}$ sheaves don't have to be schemes, and I am not comfortable with non-representable algebraic spaces.

Separated means the diagonal is proper. Properness can be checked smooth locally on the target. The pullback of the diagonal along the smooth cover $\operatorname{Spec}k \to BG \times BG$ is $G \to \operatorname{Spec}k$ so the necessary condition is also sufficient.

@DoriBejleri thanks
